# .obj file in javascript is not moving when using keyboard

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

The most important part in my code is in JavaScript. I want that my objects can move when I press "down" or "right" or etc. The problem is that object from `.json` file is moving, but object from `.obj` file is not. Is it possible to fix that?

This is my code:

```
<script>
var container, scene, camera, renderer, controls, stats;
var keyboard = new THREEx.KeyboardState();
var keyboard = new KeyboardState();
var galva;
init();
animate();
render();   
function init() 
{
    var spgeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 30, 32, 32 );
    var spmaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x00000} );
    galva = new THREE.Mesh( spgeometry, spmaterial );
    galva.position.set(125, 150, 90);
    scene.add( galva );
    var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    jsonLoader.load( "models/android.js", addModelToScene );
        var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    loader.load("models/teaport.obj", function ( object ) {

    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(  );

    object.traverse( function ( child ) {

        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

            child.material = material;
        }
    } );
    object.scale.set(50,50,50);
    scene.add( object );

} );
}

function addModelToScene( geometry, materials ) 
{
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( materials );
    c = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    c.scale.set(50,50,50);
    scene.add( c );
}

function update()
{
    keyboard.update();
        if ( keyboard.down("left") ){ 

        galva.translateX( -50 );

        }

    if ( keyboard.down("right") ){ 

        c.translateX( 50 );
        galva.translateX( 50 );
        object.translateX( 50 );
        }

    controls.update();
    stats.update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put together a jsfiddle or something similar - it could be easier to figure out. I think you end up with variable shadowing, and your "object" is simply undefined. Try following change.

```js
    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    loader.load("models/teaport.obj", function ( o ) {

    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(  );

    o.traverse( function ( child ) {

        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

            child.material = material;
        }
    } );
    o.scale.set(50,50,50);
    scene.add( o );
    
    object = o; // <-- important
```